# Call a method in the calling class on API success in android

Tags: android, api, retrofit

I use the following class to make an API call  in android using `Retrofit`

```
public Class Checkin {

    public static void checkinViaApi(CheckinSendModel checkinSendModel) {

        final ApiHandler apiHandler = new ApiHandler();
        apiHandler.setApiResponseListener(new ApiResponseListener() {

            @Override
            public void onApiResponse(ApiResponseModel apiResponse) {
                Log.i("CheckedIn","true");
            }

            @Override
            public void onApiException(Error error) {
                Log.i("fail",error.getErrorMessage());

            }
        });

        List<CheckinSendModel> checkinSendModelList = new ArrayList<CheckinSendModel>();
        checkinSendModelList.add(checkinSendModel);
        Call<ApiResponseModel> request = RetrofitRestClient.getInstance().checkinToMainEvent(checkinSendModelList,Constant.API_KEY);
        apiHandler.getData(request);
    }
}
```

I call that method as follows:

```
Checkin.checkinViaApi(checkinSendModelObject);
```

Now, when the API call is successful, I want to execute a function `checkedInSuccessfully()` in the class from where I make the call. How can I do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass in the response interface.

```
public class Checkin {

    public static void checkinViaApi(CheckinSendModel checkinSendModel, ApiResponseListener listener) {

        final ApiHandler apiHandler = new ApiHandler();
        apiHandler.setApiResponseListener(listener);
```

---

Other class - Call that method

```
CheckinSendModel model;
Checkin.checkinViaApi(model, new ApiResponseListener() {

        @Override
        public void onApiResponse(ApiResponseModel apiResponse) {
            Log.i("CheckedIn","true");
            checkedInSuccessfully();
        }

        @Override
        public void onApiException(Error error) {
            Log.i("fail",error.getErrorMessage());

        }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Interface is your handy man. Create an interface like below.

```
 Interface CheckInListener {
      void onCheckIn();
 }
```

Change the checkinViaApi() to below signature.

```
public static void checkinViaApi(CheckinSendModel checkinSendModel, CheckinListener listener) {
     @Override
     public void onApiResponse(ApiResponseModel apiResponse) {
            Log.i("CheckedIn","true");
            listener.onCheckIn();
      }
}
```

When you call the above function you can provide an instance of the interface.

```
Checkin.checkinViaApi(checkinSendModelObject, new CheckInListener() {
      @Override
      void onCheckIn() {
                //Do your action here
      }
});
```